# Is there a particular statistic to describe the degree of uniformity or 'evenness' of a field variable over an area?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have temperature data from a flat plate with spatially distributed heat sources. I'm trying to find a single statistic that describe how uniformly the temperature (and hence the thermal energy?) is distributed over the plate. If someone could point me in the right direction, I think I can follow the path to the answer.

Comment: How densely are the plate covered with measurements?

Comment: That is actually a variable I can control. For now my test case is 5 separate heat sources and the square plate is covered by 10 measurement/data collection points. I also have a simulation, where the measurement resolution is effectively the mesh resolution, which is pretty fine.

Comment: Here is [a list of similar posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=measu*+uniformity+of+dist*+answers%3A1)